# How can i get matplotlib to correctly format these datetime64 objects?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, datetime64

I'm trying to plot a horizontal bar chart in python of the following data:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hlZF.png)

Using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.barh(subset['sources'], width=subset['repairDate'], left=subset['appearanceDate'])
```

but the output gives me the dates in the x-axis as some sort of integer.

[first_chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwAZi.png)

I tried to use a custom date formatter to maybe fix that but I honestly can't tell what went on behind the scenes there, it just multiplied the number of xticks dramatically and the labels themselves seem to still be integers:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.barh(subset['sources'], width=subset['repairDate'], left=subset['appearanceDate'])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()))
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), rotation=90);
```

[attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiyKo.png)

Comment: Please don’t share pictures for data or code, if you expect help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the width to be deltas, which works fine with Matplotlib.  However, `barh` doesn't trigger the datetime units machinery (which seems an oversight), so you need to do it manually:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
start = np.array([np.datetime64('2012-01-01'), np.datetime64('2012-02-01'), np.datetime64('2012-01-15')])
stop = np.array([np.datetime64('2012-02-07'), np.datetime64('2012-02-13'), np.datetime64('2012-02-12')])
# force x axis to be times:
l, = ax.plot(stop, [0, 1, 3], '.')
ax.barh([0,1, 3], width=stop-start, left=start)
l.remove()
```

Note I've used `numpy.datetim64`, but I think pandas timedeltas should work as well (I don't use pandas so can't really test easily).

Comment: So thanks for that advice, on top of fixing my issue, plotting the deltas made the bars actually plot correctly (which I didn't even realize at the time). Can you explain which part of your code is "doing it manually" vs my code?

Comment: The "force x axis to be times" part where I add some temporary dots, and then remove them later.    There are more complicated ways to do the same thing, but that is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the matplotlib documentation, you have to use syntax like this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.barh(y, width, height=0.8, left=None,*,align='center',**kwargs)
```

rather than just using `plt.barh`

Comment: Sorry, I should have included my imports in the code above. Wouldnt is be the same if I imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt?